# How to use cat command with ignore conditions in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

The following command works fine on the command line, but not in a bash script.

```
cat dir/!(00|01)/* > all.txt
```

When executing the same command in a bash script I get the following error:

```
../scripts/preprocess.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
../scripts/preprocess.sh: line 8: `    cat dir/!(00|01)/* > all.txt'
```

Does anyone know how to get this to work in a script?

Thanks

Comment: See also [Parenthesis works in bash shell itself, but not in bash script](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157541/parenthesis-works-in-bash-shell-itself-but-not-in-bash-script) on [unix.se].

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the same shell option in the script that is set at the command line, namely `extglob`.